# How can I prevent any auto-upgrades of Mono (Xamarin) on Windows (Visual Studio) to stay synced with Mac?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, xamarin.ios, windows-installer

I use Xamarin on Windows and Mac (on Mac for iOS apps).

**The issue is** that **on Windows the Mono (Xamarin.iOS) is repeatedly updating** itself and from time to time I've got this:

> The Xamarin.Ios SDK version installed on Mac is not compatible with
>   this version of Visual Studio. Would you like us to install
>   xamarin.ios ... for you? This will overwrite any existing Xamarin.ios
>   installation on your mac.

*It's not an issue to upgrade Mac, but it is when I just need to run some code quickly* and instead having that request for the update, and *must spend some time for handling that*. (What's more proplematic that some updates of Xamarin.iOS *require newer version of XCode*, which **leads for me to stuck with the updates for two or more hours**!!!)

However, I can't find who (what app/launcher) initiates the update of Xamarin. I've **already turned off Visual Studio** any **auto-updates** in the Scheduler etc., but the issue is still happening.

**I need to control myself when I want to upgrade Xamarin** exactly!

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you need to connect the mac to debug your app on iOS .It is necessary to keep compatible the verison of xamarin.iOS between Window and Mac .

Comment: This happening because my Windows applies the auto-updates some way. If it doesn't, everything's fine.

Comment: On Visual Studio for windows ,the version of Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android will update when you update the IDE . But in Mac , you can update them individually .

Comment: Yes. It is updated with IDE (if you apply VS update). But I don't do that. This is the core of my question. Xamarin.iOS updates regularly independently from VS on my machine (apparently in background), so this is why I am having this issue.

Comment: You can add a new bug report . Help->Send feedback->report a problem .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was posted at [Microsoft's](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/781320/how-can-i-prevent-any-auto-upgrades-of-mono-xamari.html).

As it was mentioned there:

> This is indeed a known side effect of not having a direct dependency
>   on our Windows bits to our Mono bits required on the Mac. It’s an
>   infrastructure issue that made us need to rely on the published
>   products to identify what Mono version is required for the known
>   Xamarin.iOS. Due to that problem, while we know what exact Xamarin.iOS
>   version we need to install on the Mac, we look for the latest Mono
>   version published on the corresponding channel. That makes any new
>   Mono update on that channel to change the requirements for pairing a
>   given Visual Studio version to a Mac. On other words, you cannot avoid
>   that Mono update from Visual Studio on Windows and pairing to the Mac,
>   because the connection flow will detect an incompatible Mono version
>   on the Mac, which is not correct.
>
> We’re already working on an improved mechanism where Visual Studio on
>   Windows knows exactly what’s the Mono dependency and do not rely on
>   any updates for that, which should allow our users to stay on a given
>   version without changing the Mono requirement on the Mac without an
>   explicit update on Visual Studio.

As of Dec 04, 2019 it's been mentioned it's available in Preview. So, I assume, this must be fixed at least in v`16.5` version of Visual Studio.